# Buttons in Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to know whether it is possible to add buttons to a document library's column when a new item is created.
 I am working on SharePoint without using any development tools like SPD and Visual Studio.So, is there a way to use JavaScript to achieve this? Because, if it is done using java script I can add the java script code to a content editor and get the desired functionality.

Thanks

Comment: do u mean in the Editform..where we update the document metadata ?

Comment: No in default library view. On click of the button I would like to start a workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a calculated column with a defined value of "ReplaceWithButton" or something similar and then use jQuery to find and replace all instances with your button.

You may also be able to do this with XSLT which is also text based and can be added to any list view using the XSL Link field in the Miscellaneous section of the web part settings.

If you are using SP2013 you can also create your own Design Template in JavaScript which can be applied to the web part in the JS Link field in the settings.